# Undefined Method Error in Rails View (no other answer's solutions address this)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

and thanks in advance.

I have a very basic rails application, that accepts user input from a form, and displays it on a show view.

I am passing the ID of the object, in the redirect_to to the show page. The show page throws an error, and I can't figure out why. Why would the EACH method not be available to the instance variable @questions? (@questions from the show action) - Other answers addressing the same error, aren't relevant in this particular situation. Error follows:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method \`each' for #<Question:0x007fcff50ac950>):  
    1: <div class="flash_notice">flash[:notice]</div>  
    2: <% @questions.each do |q| %>  
    3: <%= q.answer %>  
    4: <% end %>  
  app/views/questions/show.html.erb:2:in   \`_app_views_questions_show_html_erb__4078795064500088796_70265573096080'

  Rendered /Users/iMR-CEO/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)  
  Rendered /Users/iMR-CEO/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)  
  Rendered /Users/iMR-CEO/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (12.6ms)
```

**Questions Controller:**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
def index
   @questions = Question.all
end

def new
  @question = Question.new
   @ques1 = "What is the most important business development task you can focus on right      now?"
end

def edit
   @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end



def show
   @questions = Question.find(params[:id])

end

def update
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
if @question.update_attributes(question_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'message'
    redirect_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'index')
else
  render("edit")
end
end

def create
@question = Question.new(question_params)
if @question.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Answer Stored.'
    redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @question.id)

else 
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end
end

def delete
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
@question = Question.find(params[:id]).destroy
flash[:notice] = "Deleted Action - Nice job"
redirect_to(:action => 'new')
end

private
def question_params
params.require(:question).permit(:answer, :question_id)
end
end
```

**Show View:**

```
<div class="flash_notice">flash[:notice]</div>
<% @questions.each do |q| %>
<%= q.answer %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes (in case necessary)**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

#get 'home/index'

#get 'home/edit'

#get 'home/delete'

#get 'home/show'

root 'home#index'

#get 'index' => 'questions#index'

#get 'questions/edit'

#get 'new' => 'questions#new'

#get 'questions/delete'

#post 'questions/destroy'

#get 'questions/show'

#post 'create' => 'questions#create'



match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

**New View:**

```
<%= form_for(@question, :url => {action: "create"}) do |f| %>
<%= f.label(:question, "Question:") %></br>
<%= @ques1 %></br></br>
<%= f.label(:question, "Answer Below") %></br>
<%= f.text_area(:answer) %></br>


<%= f.submit "Answer" %>

<% end %>
</br>

<div align="center"><%= link_to("Home", :action => 'index') %></div>
```

Comment: `Question.find` returns one record not a collection so in your show view you are trying to iterate a single object. This is the error.

Comment: Understood - So what would the correct way be to display the object that was created in the new form, on the show page? I'm gathering: you cannot use the each method, because the show action (question.find) only refers to one record, not a collection. So, to display one record, what would go on the view? Will research also.. but what would you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@questions` variable in the `show` action contains a single Question object and not an Array. The `find` method in ActiveRecord will return a single entity or raise an exception if no match is found.

This is different to the `.all()` method in ActiveRecord (e.g in the `index` action) which returns an Array of Questions or an empty array if none are found.

As the `each` method belongs to the [Array class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-each), the exception is raised when the code tries to call `each` on a Question object and not an Array object.

Comment: Definitely the case. Thanks for this. As I said in a comment above, I didn't even think about the idea that each refers to more than 1 record.

Answer (score 1):

In your `show` view you're attempting to treat the `@questions` variable as an Array-like object, but it's not an array. You probably just want to do this:

```
<%= @question.answer %>
```

As well as defining the `show` action in your controller like this:

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Now I get it. I never thought to think that Question.find is only looking for 1 record, and the each method only refers to a situation where there are many records.

Comment: @RyanBigg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854976/no-route-matches-post-sessions-new-rails-4-in-action/26855240#26855240

Answer (score 1):

change your **anction** like this:

```
 def show
```

<s>@questions = Question.find(params[:id])</s>

```
 @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end
```

show view:

```
<div class="flash_notice">flash[:notice]</div>
<%= @question.answer %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller show action `@questions` variable as an Array-like object, but not an array. When you used that `@questions.each` in show view page it iterates `@questions` object key and value pair. Change you code like this:

Question controller

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end
```

Show View:

```
<div class="flash_notice">flash[:notice]</div>    
  <%= @question.answer %>
```

Comment: Appreciate it, @KishorMohan - thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Show View:**

```
<div class="flash_notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<%= @questions.answer %>
```

Comment: Yes - this will definitely work. Now I get it! Thanks for your response.