# No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new" (rails 4 in action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following the Rails 4 In action book and I'm running into the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new"
```

I'm not sure why, as I've followed the tutorial to a T. Which leaves me to believe the tutorial itself is flawed. Anyhow, for some reason it's posting to sessions#new when it should be posting to sessions#create. What am I doing wrong?

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.where(:name => params[:signin][:name]).first
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:signin][:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
    flash[:error] = "Sorry."
    render :new
    end
  end
end
```

**sessions/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Sign in</h1>
<%= form_for :signin, method: "POST" do |f| %>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
<%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get "/signin", to: "sessions#new"
  post "/signin", to: "sessions#create"
```

Comment: you should need to specify that a form_for is a POST method - they are post by default I'd try removing it. Secondly normally you'd just write "method: :post" not "POST"). Note: this may or may not solve you problem, but worth trying.

Comment: thirdly, there's a world of difference between `:signin` and `"/signin"` - try the latter

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast, unfortunately though none of the above solved the issue.

Comment: ok, so next - you are running your server in a window right? click the "Sign in" button and show us exactly what gets logged to that window after you click.

Comment: Also, in your browser, right-click and inspect the form and see what html is actually rendered for the form

Comment: oh wait - check your tutorial, should you be using `form_for` or `form_tag` ?

Comment: What does your devise routes look like?

Comment: @TarynEast form_for, copied the new.html.erb code entirely.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML form look like?

Comment: Also - `rake routes` is your friend.. do you see the path printed out that matches up with what's rendered in the HTML form?

Comment: Strange: <form method="post" action="/sessions/new" accept-charset="UTF-8"> why is it rendering sessions/new? the method on form_for is post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct there is an error in this book.

When you have a form for tag

```
<%= form_for :signin, method: "POST" do |f| %>
```

If rails doesn't know what `:signin` means, then it will simply copy the current url and will submit the form to that url (in this case 'sessions/new'), using the post verb (whether you specify it or not!)

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions/new" method="post">
....
```

Obviously, that's not necessarily what you want because you don't have a /sessions/new for post HTTP verb,  I think the easiest solution would be to specify a route

```
post "/signin", to: "sessions#create", as: "signin"
```

and in your form_for

```
<%= form_for signin_path do |f| %>
```